# Is there a way to upgrade my lubuntu version to 20.04 and wipe the hard drive at the same time without using a dvd or usb?

Tags: system-installation, upgrade, lubuntu

I want to upgrade from Lubuntu 19.04 to 20.04 and I am curious if there is some way of doing this from the terminal while erasing all my old files at the same time. I think there's a term for upgrading an OS while wiping the hard drive but I can't remember it, so I haven't been able to find anything searching for pre-existing answers.

I am not sure if this matters, but I originally downloaded Lubuntu 19.04 from lubuntu.net, not lubuntu.me. It's running on a chromebook with the original OS mostly removed. I have it set up so if anything goes wrong I can just reinstall chrome OS before overwriting it again.

I don't have a cd/dvd drive, and I only have one usb stick, so I'd rather not go through the hassle of installing from usb.

Comment: I think it is easiest and most straight-forward to create a live drive with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and install from that drive. It means, if you have valuable files on the USB drive,  you have to copy them to some other location, maybe into the internet cloud (there are several free storage locations). On the other hand, a small USB pendrive is rather cheap. You need no big or fancy drive for the purpose of installing Ubuntu (a 4 GB USB 2 drive is enough).

Comment: If you are using `grub` to boot your system (I don't know if your chromebook uses it), you can make `grub` boot an ISO that is installed on your hdd/ssd which can then be used to install to other portions of the disk. If you wanted to use all the disk it maybe possible with *toram* options but I've not done that sorry (I never overwritten the partition the ISO came from). The ISO can also be written to a partition & that partition made to operate as a 'live' from which you install, but do you have a partition to use for that purpose?  Thumb-drive is usually easier.